# Issues on Exporting dynamically generated div using jspdf in angular2 project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, jspdf

I'm using `jspdf` to print `div` s in my project. I recently realized that this doesn't print when a div includes some dynamic contents. What I mean is that if there is a simple angular if statement, jspdf doesn't print it. Here is a sample:

In my HTML:

```
<div id="content" #content>
   <p>This sections is printed</p>
   <p> {{ item.id }} is also printed</p>
</div>
```

This code below throws error which can be found below the html code:

```
<div id="content" #content>
   <p *ngIf="item.id === 'sample'">this is NOT printed</p>
</div>
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined at f.renderParagraph (jspdf.min.js:97)...

here is the typescript code I use:

```
@ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;    
public downloadPDF () {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    const content = this.content.nativeElement;
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

    const fileName = 'test';
    doc.save(fileName + '.pdf');
}
```

Again the first div prints as pdf just fine. But the second div doesn't. I suspect that the issue is angular if statement. But I couldn't find a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Structural directive Try This

Hidden Property Binding

```
<div id="content" #content>
   <p [hidden]="item.id !== 'sample'">this is NOT printed</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works but not in my case.Based on the if statements, I display all cases. So I need to export whatever the case is.

Comment: using ngIf also remove and add element based on your condion.

Comment: both are works similar except hidden will load the data and mark them with the hidden HTML attribute. behind the scene hidden attribute use css propery display:none, but ngIf remove the element from dom

Comment: Let me try to implement on my actual project and see what is going o happen.